# mysql group_by only returns first row

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-by

I'm new here and and need some help with mysql query.

I have this query to retrieve several rows in a join query.

```
SELECT   category.category, category_color.color,
SUM(sales.quantity) AS quantity, SUM(sales.price) AS total, sales.id_payment_type,
                    sales.price
                FROM sales
            INNER JOIN 
                category        USING (id_category)
            INNER JOIN 
                shop_session    USING (id_shop_session)
            INNER JOIN 
                category_color  USING (id_category)
            WHERE shop_session.is_active = 1
            AND category.id_lang = "._ID_LANG_."
            AND shop_session.id_shop = ".$_SESSION['id_shop']."
            GROUP BY category.category
            ORDER BY category.category
```

I've achieved grouping by category is the first purpose , but when I need to retrive some data like "price" or "id_payment_type" mysql only returns the first row, and I need to get all rows from the query. I don't know how can I solve this query. Please help!

My sales db structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
```

`id_sale` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_product` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_category` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_employee` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_payment_type` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_sale_type` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_shop_session` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(17,2) NOT NULL,
  `amount` float NOT NULL,
  `invoice` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_sale` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_sale`,`id_product`,`id_category`,`id_employee`,`id_payment_type`,`id_sale_type`,`id_shop_session`),
  KEY `id_sale` (`id_sale`)
)

And this is my db structure for category table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
```

`id_category` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_lang` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_active` int(1) NOT NULL
)

Comment: Hello Daniel...could you please post your table structure, with sample data and the expected output of the query...also a hardcoded query should be helpfull for testing purposes...cheers.

Comment: probably you're only fetching a single row. e.g. `mysqli_fetch_row()` only returns one row of results at a time. you need to call it multiple times to get all the rows. That or you're grouping wrong and getting a "collapsed" result of the group.

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)?

Comment: The answer to your question is that you would not use a `group by` query for what you want.  That would be a different type of query.

Comment: I've added my db structure. I'm using mysqli_fetch_assoc() to retrieve data. Is very important for my to group by category. I've tried with group_concat() but that was not util for my query. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   category.category, category_color.color,
SUM(sales.quantity) AS quantity, SUM(sales.price) AS total, sales.id_payment_type,
sales.price FROM sales
INNER JOIN  category        USING (id_category)
INNER JOIN  shop_session    USING (id_shop_session)
INNER JOIN  category_color  USING (id_category)
WHERE shop_session.is_active = 1
AND category.id_lang = "._ID_LANG_."
AND shop_session.id_shop = ".$_SESSION['id_shop']."
GROUP BY category.category
ORDER BY category.category
```

This query will give you the first row of every category you have because you are using a group by and i say the first because you are using an order by with an implicit ASC.

If you want all the id_payment_type or prices of every category you can't group by.